# Can't copy into + and * registers in Vim on MacOS

Tags: macos, vim

I am using alacritty 0.12.0 and Vim 9.0 with `+xterm_clipboard` and `+clipboard`. When I open Vim, type a word `hello` and then place the cursor inside the word and do:

- :set showcmd
- "+yiw
- "+p

I see "E353: Nothing in register +". The same for register `*`.

`:set clipboard?` gives me `clipboard=`. I did actually set it to this value since with the default of `autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux` I get the following strange behaviour. When I'm using visual selection it actually uses `VisualNOS` as if Vim didn't own the selection.

So all in all it seems that there's some strange interaction between Vim and the system clipboard.

Comment: How did you get that Vim? Why don't you open an issue where you got it? Do you have that problem in Terminal.app? Without your config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by "romainl" turned out to be the crucial missing piece.

I'm installing Vim from [Nix Home Manager](https://nix-community.github.io/home-manager/), which seems to be missing certain Darwin (MacOS) features that are necessary for the system integration.

By installing `vim-darwin` instead of just `vim` I was able to solve the issue, so:

```
{
  programs.vim = {
    packageConfigurable = pkgs.vim-darwin;
    enable = true;
  };
}
```